# How to reuse my docker images to create new laravel project

Tags: laravel, docker

I used the default installation of Laravel to create my first project in Laravel, but now I'm wondering how to create another one by reusing the containers from the first installation. Once I run the code for the first installation again, if there is a new update in the images, it duplicates the images because they are not the same and I don't want that.

I don't have an image of the duplicate containers because I already deleted them :(, I'm using Docker on Windows with WSL

Comment: How did you setup your project? Did you use docker-compose? If yes here are what **I** think happens when using docker. In docker-compose, if the entry under the service is "image" then it will **use** that image from the docker source (someone online) then download it to your local PC. every services that uses the same **image** entry in the docker-compose will use the same **image**.

Comment: If you used "build" (with dockerfile), then it will **create** a new image under your project name (or under container_name). If you are using the build option. I suggest you export your **image** then update docker-compose to use the exported image. (did not test this)

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve] (for example, including the two images' Dockerfiles) and explain in more detail what's going wrong?